# Cannot nest a Javascript function within a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I have the following function setup:

```
function disableButtons(){
    $('div.test').block({
        message: '<h1>Processing</h1>',
        css: { border: '3px solid #a00' }
        });
    }
```

Now I have another function I would like to call that from:

```
function test(){
    //call function here    
    disableButtons();
}
```

If I put the exact information of function 1 into function 2, it works, but not if I call function 1 directly from function 2.  Here is how I would like it to work:

```
function1 () {
//function statements
}

function2 () {
    function1();
}
```

It seems to me this should just "work" but I'm thinking something is wrong with my syntax, perhaps, because it is not working.

EDIT:
Here is my actual code...

```
function disableButtons(){
            $('div.test').block({
                message: '<h1>Processing</h1>',
                css: { border: '3px solid #a00' }
            });

function selectEmployeeInfo(){
    disableButtons();

        document.forms[0].action="userGet.do";
        document.forms[0].submit();

    }
```

Comment: Post your actual code.

Comment: Posting it in my original post, now.

Comment: Where do you call `test()`?

Comment: this should work. What happens when you debug it? I suspect there's an error somewhere cause it to fail. I'd look into the block function and the parameters in that.  If you comment out the block function and add an alert on the disabledButtons, does the alert fire?

Comment: It looks like `disableButtons` is defined inside another function block? If so, you cannot call it directly (javascript functions are first-class functions).

Comment: You have an extra `});` that you don't need after disableButtons. See my answer.

Comment: I'm not familar with jQuery's `block()`. What does that do?

Comment: @XGundam05 I think you're correct in that being the problem. If so, is what I'm trying to do not even possible? Is there some way to make function1 a global function?

Comment: @dihakz, see JAM's answer. You just need to define the function in the global scope and call it where necessary.

Comment: block() is from the jQuery BlockUI plugin <http://www.malsup.com/jquery/block/>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm guessing you didn't provide all of your code, just the necessary bits; so I'm assuming  that your `disableButtons` function is scoped, which means it's not a global function:

```
// Assuming missing bits of code, probably something similar to '$(function(){' 

    function disableButtons(){
        $('div.test').block({
            message: '<h1>Processing</h1>',
            css: { border: '3px solid #a00' }
        });

    }

}); // <-- Ending of scope?


function selectEmployeeInfo(){
    disableButtons();   // Undefined because of scope?

    document.forms[0].action="userGet.do";
    document.forms[0].submit();

}
```

Try moving the `});` before the `function disableButtons()` or after the `selectEmployeeInfo()` definition, and see what happens :)

Comment: Thank you -- that was the exact problem I had.

Answer (score 1):

You need the `function`keyword to declare functions:

```
function function1 () {
//function statements
}

function function2 () {
    function1();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Syntax error, you have too many brackets.

```
function disableButtons(){
        $('div.test').block({
            message: '<h1>Processing</h1>',
            css: { border: '3px solid #a00' }
        });

    }


function selectEmployeeInfo(){
    disableButtons();

        document.forms[0].action="userGet.do";
        document.forms[0].submit();

}
```

Comment: Thank you for this. The syntax error was in my copying it over here, since I had to strip out extraneous code that was irrelevant (and I forgot those brackets.)

Comment: Aha. You can declare disableButtons outside of the containing brackets you had (presumably from a jQuery event or similar) and then simply put `disableButtons();` into the jQuery event.

Comment: Thank you -- that is exactly the solution I needed. :)